# Debug Windows Phone 10 Continuum applications

Tags: debugging, windows-phone, visual-studio-debugging, miracast

How can one debug Windows Phone 10 Continuum apps? The only option I found so far is to use Continuum with a wireless (Miracast) receiver. Is it possible to debug without such a receiver?

Regards,